# failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:81

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm working on a legacy PHP project I cannot start the project I got the error,

> failed to open stream: Permission denied in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:81

It is running on XAMPP on Ubuntu server.

I've have been try a lot of commands (below) but nothing works.

1. sudo chmod -R 777 storage
2. sudo chmod -R 775 storage
3. php artisan view:clear
4. php artisan config:clear
5. php artisan config:cache
6. php artisan key:generate
7. composer dump-autoload
8. sudo chown -R daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs
9. sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

Please help.

Comment: can you check you storage folder there must be these folder present `storage/framework/cache` and `storage/framework/views` rest you can match with  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/8.x/storage/framework

Comment: Thanks @KamleshPaul Already created but it's not working.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/6274211) SO answer by @bgies

Comment: FileSystem.php  is trying to access a file that is somewhere on the disk. It might be that it is outside of the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory. Find out the path and set the permission for that path.

Comment: Hey!! How did you solve your issues?